# Programmatically Getting List of all Running Processes on Mac

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, process, macos-sierra

I'm looking for a way to get all running processes on the Mac that satisfies these requirements:

1.) ALL processes (system and user)

2.) A unique process name for a given vendor's process. For example, an application from two vendors might have the same process name (as seen in Activity Monitor). With the below code, the bundleIdentifier would give an unique name. The activity monitor might show multiple processes with the same process name, but that process name would be unique to that process.

3.) If the process has a window

The code below will do 2 and 3, but not 1 (it only gets the user's processes).

```
for (NSRunningApplication app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]) {
    NSString *uniqueName = app.bundleIdentifier;
    BOOL hasWindow = (app.activationPolicy == NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular)?YES:NO;
}
```

Does anyone know of another way to satisfy all 3 requirements?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you need #2 for? The system e.g. launches several copies of processes like mdworker to do work in parallel, so this is an actual impossibility. But depending on what you're actually trying to do, there might be identifiers that are "unique enough" for you. E.g. if you just want to keep track of a process during runtime, you can use the PID, but that's random and only valid at runtime. Path can change (even while a process is running), but can be good enough for certain use cases ...

Comment: Look into the CGWindowList if you need to find all windows on your Mac (for the current user). ISTR they can provide you the PID for each window, which you can use to correlate them with process lists obtained from elsewhere. I think they even include a process name you can show to the user (but not one sufficient for #2).

Answer (score 1):

Go pull the sources for `ps` from the Darwin Sources archive (it'll be buried in one of the system tools archives and not on its own) and start there.

That'll get you (1).   (2) isn't possible; two processes can have the same name (but every process has to have a unique PID-- use that).

(3) You'll have to go and plunder the window server somehow.   There are probably snippets on GitHub that demonstrate how to do that, I'd think.

Comment: I'll rephrase #2. Need a way to humanly differentiate two process names from different vendors.

Comment: `ps` source code here: https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-174.0.1/ps/

Comment: @bbum - Is this the only possible way for (1). Or is there any API update recently. since I need to achieve (1).