# Mac OS X - Get list of all processes running on the system?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, core-services

I am searching for an API to get the list of processes running on the system (including the process launched by other users on the system).

I see lot of questions are already raises. But It was older questions.

1. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620647/programmatically-getting-list-of-all-running-processes-on-mac)  - which answers to use `ps` command and parse the output.
2. `NSWorkspace` provides `runningApplications` - which returns the processes under the current user.

Is there any API introduced in the recent updates to get all processes running on the system?

Comment: To clarify, I think your "Question 1" link was suggesting to look at the source code for ps and do what it does, not to fork a ps process and parse its output.  Although that would also be an option, I suppose; but the ps source code isn't that bad, I've plundered from it myself.

Comment: You can ask the kernel using `sysctl`, e.g.: https://gist.github.com/s4y/1173880/9ea0ed9b8a55c23f10ecb67ce288e09f08d9d1e5